# My while loop iterations are not being displayed for the rows in a .csv file

Tags: c, while-loop, iteration

basically the while loop is either not looping for the total amount of rows in the .csv file, or the there is something wrong with the display of the file, it is supposed to display that there is 6 rows in a .csv 6x2 array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {

    //Declaration
        FILE *fp;
        int c=0,i=0,j=0,g=0;
        double poly;
        char file[100];
        int A[50][2];

        //Asking for polynomial order
        printf("Please input a polynomial order (1-4): ");
        scanf("%lf",&poly);

        //Enter the name of the data file to open
        printf("Please enter the name of the data file to open: ");
        scanf("%s",file);
        printf("\n");

        fp = fopen(file,"r");

        //Scan and store the lines of the file
        while (fscanf(fp, "%d,%d,",&A[c][0],&A[c][1])==2) {
                c++;
                printf("reading line %d\n",c);
        }

    printf("Total data points (x,y) read from file: %d\n",c);
```

Contents of test1.csv file:

```
-3.000,0.9,
-2.00,0.8,
-1.000,0.4,
-0.200,0.2,
1.000,0.1,
3.000,0,
```

Comment: `"%d,%d,"` That trailing comma looks suspicious. Doubt that the CSV file will end with a comma. Which means it will fail to match for at least the end part. But  there is not enough info to say for sure. Please give the exact file contents, input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: @kaylum sorry, yes the .csv file I just added has a %d,%d, which was what my professor suggested I change in the first iteration where in my source code I just had %d,%d. I ended up changing it with that having no affect on the problem, Sorry for the bad post, Im used to reddit and this format was not normal for me, will be aware for the future.

Comment: `%d` is for integers. You have floats in the file. So the `fscanf` will not match those correctly.